# Suppress or catch() invalid function call - PHP

Tags: php

Have a series of functions I am calling dynamically sort of like this:

```
$function = 'someFunction';
$x = $function();
```

.. however, if the function expects parameters, and I don't code it in the call, I seem to crash the page. For example:

```
function someFunction( $in_param1 ) {
  return "SUCCESS";
}

$function = 'someFunction';
// this next line does not work
$x = $function() or die("error");
```

How can I handle this kind of error?

Thanks -

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can catch this using the [set_error_handler](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) function:

```
function handle_errors( $errno, $errstr )
{
    die( "Your error will be caught here" );
}

set_error_handler( "handle_errors" );

$function = 'someFunction';
$x = $function();
```

Comment: This is a good answer. I don't know why I didn't think of an error handler as a way to essentially "catch" errors.

Answer (score 3):

Suppress? Yes. Catch? [See don.neufeld's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779534/suppress-or-catch-invalid-function-call-php/779539#779539).

```
$x = @$function();
```

According to [this page](http://us.php.net/operators.errorcontrol), you can enable a specific INI setting so that you can read errors suppressed in this manner.

Answer (score 2):

You could redefine your function with default values for the arguments required like

```
function someFunction( $in_param1=null ) {
  return "SUCCESS";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about suppressing, but you can get more information about the functions with the [`ReflectFunction`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.reflection.php#language.oop5.reflection.reflectionfunction) class.

```
<?php
function foo($a, $b, $c) {}

$func = new ReflectionFunction('foo');
echo $func->getNumberOfParameters();
```

This outputs "3".